# Trouble compile C code containing ncurses library: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"

Tags: c, terminal, colors, ncurses, alacritty

I am trying to use the library `ncurses` on my macos 11.6.1 with the terminal alacritty. When I try to compile this code (copied from there: https://www.viget.com/articles/game-programming-in-c-with-the-ncurses-library/)

```
// demo.c
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 initscr();
 noecho();
 curs_set(FALSE);

 sleep(1);

 endwin(); // Restore normal terminal behavior
}
```

, I get the following message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_curs_set", referenced from:
      _main in house-efc906.o
  "_endwin", referenced from:
      _main in house-efc906.o
  "_initscr", referenced from:
      _main in house-efc906.o
  "_noecho", referenced from:
      _main in house-efc906.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does this mean that `ncurses` is not installed on my system and if yes, how should I instal it?

Comment: Looks like you are not *linking* against the library... What is your build command?

Comment: Oh you are right: I added `-lncurses` to the command `gcc demo.c` and it worked. Many thanks @EugeneSh.